# Can't add PXDBLocalizableString field to DAC without a NoteID column

Tags: acumatica

We are trying to make the EPPosition DAC description field localizable.

For the PXDBLocalizableString attribute to work properly, a PXNote (NoteID) is required within the DAC.

The problem is that if we add a NoteID to the EPPosition DAC, it gets deleted every time we update the database since the field is not preceded with the 'Usr' prefix as required for custom fiels.

If we add the 'Usr' prefix, then, the PXDBLocalizableString complains that 'NoteID' does not exist.

Comment: What if you add both fields (UsrNoteID & NoteID) and NoteID is unbound and linked to UsrNoteID? UsrNoteID is just the storage of the value

Comment: "Usr" prefix is not required at all. It's just been added by the system automatically for having difference between system fields and custom field. If you try to create the class from already created new table you will see that

Comment: If adding fields to a system table, the Usr prefix would be required for the column to stay in the table after upgrades. Also, extension tables do not support NoteID so the only way is to implement into the base table.

Comment: Brendan, I tough and try about your suggestion, the problem is the PXDBLocalizableString is really looking for the NoteID field in the database on its side. It kind of bypass the EPPosition DAC it seems...